# Bad refreshing of the UITableViewCell after edit mode canceled by the swipe gesture

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, ios7

After canceling a table view cell edit mode using a swipe gesture, the left side of the cell is not refreshing. Canceling by a tap works okay, it's only an issue with a swipe.

Top image it's cell in edit mode. Bottom image - cell after canceling edit mode by the swipe gesture.

[image: UITableViewCell edit mode]

How can I resolve this problem under iOS 7?

Comment: Please show what code you've tried.

Comment: This is controlled by the OS

Comment: Animating the delete button into place is done by the OS, telling the table that you're editing, when you're finished editing, and what editing style you want is done by you.  Also, it's not clear from your image which one is the bad refresh.  I'm assuming it's the bottom image with the white area that looks out of place (you said it was the right side though)?

Comment: Top image it's cell in edit mode. Bottom image - cell after canceling edit mode by the swipe gesture.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a custom layout for your table view cell, check the autoresizing or autolayout settings.  Make sure your background will always resize itself to fill the entire cell.